# What is the difference between alignof(i) and alignof(decltype(i))?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

alignas(16) int i;

int main()
{

    std::cout << alignof(i) << std::endl; // output: 16 and warning
    std::cout << alignof(decltype(i)) << std::endl; // output: 4
}
```

What does `alignof(i)` and `alignof(decltype(i))` do? I would have expected `alignof(i)` not to compile and `alignof(decltype(i))` to return 16.

Comment: the type of `i` is `int`, so you are seeing `alignof(int)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alignof(i)` is the alignment of the `i` variable, which is explicitly being set to 16, regardless of its type.

`alignof(decltype(i))`, aka `alignof(int)`, is the natural alignment (`sizeof(int)`, ie 4 in this case) for all `int` variables that are not otherwise aligned.

Comment: Since alignof(i) gives a warning, is there a way to determine the alignment of i without warning?

Comment: @JohnFreeman1212 What's the warning? An "ISOC++ doesn't allow this" compatibility warning?

Comment: @JohnFreeman1212 What is the actual warning you are getting?

Comment: Probably `<source>:8:18: warning: ISO C++ does not allow 'alignof' with a non-type [-Wpedantic]` or `<source>:8:18: warning: 'alignof' applied to an expression is a GNU extension [-Wgnu-alignof-expression]` - live - https://godbolt.org/z/57a6n7eee

Comment: `warning: ISO C++ does not allow 'alignof' with a non-type [-Wpedantic]`

Comment: @JohnFreeman1212 The argument to `alignof` is required by the Standard to be a type. GCC is allowing variables by extension. If you make a type, [example](https://godbolt.org/z/G5rET4xaz) you're good to go. In GCC, anyway. Not sure how kosher this actually is. Never tried it in Visual Studio, for example.

Comment: @user4581301 I get compilation errors with clang and MSVC - live - https://godbolt.org/z/G5qqfMejj looks like gcc is being too permissive, see also [CWG 1437. alignas could be used in alias declarations](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/1437.html)

Comment: @RichardCritten that's about what I suspected when I couldn't find support in the Standard. `-pedantic` should be calling that out. Not sure why I didn't pop that into Compiler Explorer and try it out myself, especially after using it to demo the GCC version.